# Build in TFS with multiple project is not taking the correct transformation web config

Tags: msbuild

I have a solution in VS2010 and it has three project, two of these projects have web config file, the projects have web config transformation for each environment (dev, test and prod).
At the process for TFS build option, I have the  at the MSBuild Arguments :  /p:DeployOnBuild=True

Everything looks good, the drop folder, the zip files and all structure for the final deployment. The issue I am facing the web config for test and prod is not created correctly after the final deployment, I could see at the drop folders the file projectName.SetParameters.xml, it contains the values for development when the build has been QUEUE for Test and Prod. One of the project has the correct web config (test and prod) but the other project has always the dev webconfig.
Is it a bug in the MS Build? What am I missing in the build parameters?

When I create a build deployment package the web config transformation creates the correct web config file, no issues with this process, but I do not want to use  build deployment package to deploy my solution.
Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In your Build Definition you probably defined the Configurations to use. Part of that also defines something like `Any CPU` or `x86`. As it turns out the solution the Platform "Any CPU" has a space where in the project files the Platform `Any CPU` does not have a space.

I found the best way to get around this was to leave the Platform blank and only put in the configuration name. VS will pop up a warning letting you know that there is data missing, you can just hit "Yes" to save it anyways. Alternatively you can just type in your configurations like the following `|Release,|Debug`.

The pattern is [PlatformName]|[ConfigurationName],[PlatformName]|[ConfigurationName],...